# Button needs to be clicked twice to be hidden

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started to learn Unity and C# cause I want to make a game. But I'm stuck here because of a button problem.

When I run the following code with Unity, I get the label and "skip" button as I wanted.

But when I press the button, only the toggles come out. Label and button aren't hidden. Then only when I click it at second time, they are hidden.

**How can I fix this so that by clicking the button "skip" hides the button and the label along with showing the toggles.**

Thanks for viewing my question.

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if (!textfin)
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), text, guiStyle);
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width * 4 / 5, 0, Screen.width / 5, Screen.height / 5), "SKIP"))
        {
            textfin = true;
        }
    }
    else{
        easy = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(Screen.width / 4, 0, Screen.width / 2, Screen.height * 3 / 8), easy, "easy");
        if (easy)
        {
            normal = false;
            hard = false;
            Title.difficulty = 1;
        }
        normal = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(Screen.width / 4, Screen.height * 5 / 16, Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 4), normal, "normal");
        if (normal)
        {
            easy = false;
            hard = false;
            Title.difficulty = 2;
        }
        hard = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(Screen.width / 4, Screen.height * 9 / 16, Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 4), hard, "hard");
        if (hard)
        {
            normal = false;
            easy = false;
            Title.difficulty = 3;
        }
        if (easy || normal || hard)
        {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 4, Screen.height * 13 / 16, Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 8), "Proceed"))
            {
                Application.LoadLevel("Home");
            }
        }
    }
}

void Start () {
    message = "THis is Text for trial slow slow";
    text = "";
    StartCoroutine(TypeText());
}

void Update () {
    if (text == message){
        textfin = true;
    }
}

IEnumerator TypeText()
{
    foreach (char letter in message.ToCharArray())
    {
        text += letter;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(letterPause);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about your variable `textfin`. Couldn't it be that the Skip button is created twice, at the same position... Did you try to debug, with visual debugger or prints?

Comment: Opps I added the script to two separate Objects... which created two buttons like you said... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I try your code, the SKIP button disappear on click.

In your case, the script is probably added twice in the scene.

Also consider that Unity 4.6 introduces a new UI system you should use. See [this video](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui).

Comment: Oh my god... I'm really sorry. you were right I added the script twice to the scene... Oppps. I was just looking at the script it self. Sorry for my mistake :(